# Некорректно работает switch и инструкция if в Си

Tags: c, mingw

```
/*
* Программа просит пользователя ввести название карты в игре блекджек и оценивает их значимость:
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char card_name[3]; // Создаем массив с 4 ячейками
    puts("Введите название карты: "); // Пользователь вводит карту
    scanf("3%s", card_name); 
    printf("%s\r\n", card_name);
    int val = 0; // Очки которые будет получать пользователь в зависимости от карт

    switch(card_name[0]) // Оцениваем то что ввел пользователь
    {
        // В случае попадания Короля, дамы или джэка присваиваем значение 10 (т.е + 10 очков)
        case 'K':
        case 'Q':
        case 'J':
            val = val + 10;
            break;
        // Если попадет Ace (туз) то присваиваем значение 11
        case 'A':
            val = val + 11;
            break;
        //Во всех остальных случаях просто переводим string value в int с помощью atoi
        default:
            val = atoi(card_name);
            break;
    }
    // Если значение будет больше 2 и меньше 7 одновременно, то счетчик увеличиться
    if ((val > 2) && (val < 7)) 
        puts("Счетчик увеличился");
    // Если значение будет равнятся 10 то счетчик уменьшится
    else if (val == 10)
        puts("Счетчик уменьшился");

    // Выводим ценность карты ввиде числа
    printf("Ценность карты: %i\r\n:", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Когда ввожу в поле 'A' то ценность карты почему-то оценивается в 0 очков.
Также почему-то некорректно работает оценка "мусорных карт" которые меньше 10. Их счетчик не увеличивается и не уменьшается. Программа завершается сразу после ценности карт.

Кажется что где-то я совершил ошибку, буду очень рад если поправите!
Си начал изучать буквально пару дней назад..

Comment: А вы простите, 1) в switch проверяете русскую букву А или английскую? 2) при вводе вы вводите русскую букву А или английскую. Они так похожи, в не зависимости какой язык программирования.

Comment: @nick_n_a, ошибка раньше.

Comment: Да, точно @Qwertiy я сразу не увидел что ошибка в scanf, кстати интересно  что написал автору printf следующий за scanf.

Comment: @nick_n_a ввожу только английскими буквами. Кодировка на minGw стоит utf-8, то же самое в Sublime. Сейчас попробовал кириллицей ввести, выходит тот же самый результат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> scanf("3%s", card_name);
> ```

```
scanf("%3s", card_name);
```

Тогда всё работает: http://ideone.com/jrp2bs

И вообще, на самом деле должно быть `%2s`, а не `%3s`.

Comment: Спасибо но не помогло...

Comment: Ценность карты при вводе А также по 0, хотя должно быть 11..

Comment: @Klugge, да ладно? http://ideone.com/jrp2bs

Comment: А скажите что вам пишет `printf("%s\r\n", card_name);` ? И лучше его поменять на  `printf("%s %i\r\n", card_name, card_name[0]);` что б было понятно что у вас с кодировкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy Видимо проблема в моем компиляторе? Код у меня идентичный

Comment: Вводите всё английскими. С русским тяжелее дружить. (особенно если не понятно какая кодировка консоли, среды и т д)

Comment: @nick_n_a, так он в комментарии у вопроса написал, что вводит английскими.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://s12.postimg.org/em5gbi7d9/image.png

Comment: @Klugge, потому что не надо нажимать Enter перед вводом?

Comment: @Qwertiy простите, но какой Enter? Если бы я нажал на enter он бы отступил на одну строку.

Comment: @Klugge, сорри, я перепутал puts и printf. В любом случае, а вывод-то где? Должны быть две строки с буквой `A`, а на скриншоте только одна. Подебажь наконец.